# Jquery countdownTimer Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded this jquery plugin: http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/
specifically to use the `Reverse countdown to zero from time set to only minutes` timer.
I am pretty sure I followed the instructions correctly but the plugin does not work. I have never used jQuery or plugins before, so I'm not sure if I am missing something or just doing something completely wrong (or both).

My Javascript test alert does run.

I will attach my code for you all to look at. Not sure if it has to do with my file paths, but I've attached an image of that as well. Please tell me what could be causing the problem and how to fix. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="timer/LIB/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="timer/jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timer/CSS/jquery.countdownTimer.css"/>
  
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
  alert("working");
    
    </script>
  
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("tester");
  </script>

  <div id="main"><span id="m_timer"></span></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
  {
   $("#m_timer").countdowntimer({
    minutes : 2‚
    size : "lg"
   });
  })
    </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is a picture of my project folder, containing the files:**

[image]

Comment: @madalinivascu It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on line 49  (this line:  size : "lg" ) but I'm not sure what it would be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="timer/LIB/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="timer/jquery.countdownTimer.js"></script> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timer/CSS/jquery.countdownTimer.css"/>
  
 <script type="text/javascript">
 
  alert("working");
    
    </script>
  
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("tester");
  </script>

  <div id="main"><span id="m_timer"></span></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function()
  {
   $("#m_timer").countdowntimer({
    minutes : 2‚
    size : "lg"
   });
  })
    </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got it fixed. *hangs head in shame...*
Thank you for your help.